# How To find number of orbits in S3 by using burnside's Formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

How to find the number of orbits in $S_3$ under $H=\langle(123)\rangle$.
By conjugation action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of $A_3$ is in its own orbit. Then by direct calculation you can show that the remaining elements, which are all of order $2$, are all in the same orbit. Thus the number of orbits is $4$.

If we want to use Burnside's formula, note that each of $(123)$ and $(132)$ have $3$ fixed points, and the identity has $6$, so the result is $(3+3+6)/3=4$.